# how to crop multiple objects from an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

This is the code of object detection from a video.

I want to crop objects from this video frame by frame.

```
videoSource = vision.VideoFileReader('viptraffic.avi','ImageColorSpace','Intensity'...
'VideoOutputDataType','uint8');

detector = vision.ForegroundDetector(...
   'NumTrainingFrames', 5, ... 
   'InitialVariance', 30*30);

 blob = vision.BlobAnalysis(...
   'CentroidOutputPort', false, 'AreaOutputPort', false, ...
   'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
   'MinimumBlobAreaSource', 'Property', 'MinimumBlobArea', 250);

 shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor','White');

videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();

while ~isDone(videoSource)

 frame  = step(videoSource);
 fgMask = step(detector, frame);
 bbox   = step(blob, fgMask);
 out    = step(shapeInserter, frame, bbox); 
 step(videoPlayer, out); 
end
release(videoPlayer);  
release(videoSource);
```

when I want to crop bbox from frame 
it always give me error "invalid input arguments"

if I write this this command.

```
 frame(bbox(1):bbox(1)+bbox(3), bbox(2):bbox(2)+bbox(4), :);
```

"Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error came.
please help me how to crop objects from image

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
frame(bbox(2):bbox(2)+bbox(4), bbox(1):bbox(1)+bbox(3), :);
```

The values in `bbox` are in format `[ x y w h ]` while the indices into `frame` should be in row-column order: you need to change the order of x and y to row-column.

Comment: I don't know how to change x any y to row-column @Shai

Comment: @user3551081 you just change the order as I wrote in my answer. Try spotting the difference between your line of code to mine.

Comment: use debug mode and check the size of `frame` and the location of `bbox`. You might find `dbstop if error` command useful.

Comment: If you use the syntax above, you need to ensure that the bounding box co-ordinates, with the width and height, are to be integers.  I suspect this will be the case, but always something to keep in mind. Also, FWIW, use `imcrop` instead.  You can achieve the same thing by: `out = imcrop(frame, bbox);`.

Comment: @rayryeng imcrop function also give error which I already mention

Comment: Then your bounding box is obviously not right. Don't know what to tell you. Do what Shai suggested and debug your code. See what `bbox` is as well as the size of your image. It's not our job to debug your code.

Comment: @DarkVampire it is also possible `bbox` is empty - no object was detected for a specific frame. You should check for this as well.

Comment: yes this is also a possibility and I already put if condition there to check if bbox is empty don't crop from frame

Comment: @DarkVampire Update your post with your current code.  This back and forth business is a bit tiresome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle cases when no boxes have been detected (`bbox` is empty) and when more than one box is detected (`bbox` is an M-by-2 matrix).

So you should have a loop:

```
for i = 1:size(bbox, 1)
  croppedImage = frame(bbox(i, 2):bbox(i, 2)+bbox(i, 4), bbox(i, 1):bbox(i, 1)+bbox(i, 3), :);
  % do something wiht croppedImage
end
```

Alternatively, you can use the `imcrop` function:

```
croppedImage = imcrop(bbox(i, :));
```

Just be aware that `imcrop` will return an array 1 pixel smaller in x and y, than the other approach.